# Imagem de fundo do navbar Bootstrap não repetir no menu estendido no responsivo

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou com um problema na versão responsiva do navbar. Coloquei uma imagem de fundo conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para isso, fiz dessa forma:

```
.navbar{
    padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
    background: url('../imagens/barra-superior.png') no-repeat; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Mas quando tento visualizar no responsivo, essa imagem ela "estica". Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O fundo cinza escuro do menu, está dessa forma:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar .navbar-collapse{
        z-index: 999999999999999999999999999999;
        background-color: #343A40;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

Como faço para que a imagem não estique e permaneça o fundo cinza pegando de ponta a ponta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vc pode corrigir esse `padding`, usando margens negativas. Tudo bem que não é muito elegante, mas customizar a `navbar` do BS sempre é meio chato mesmo. Além disso, vc está usando uma `div.container` dentro da `navbar` com o restante do conteúdo dentro. A classe `.container` por default já tem uns espaçamentos que acho que estão te atrapalhando... De qq forma segue uma opção com uns ajustes.

Sobre o Background não tem muito o que fazer, como vc está usando o `size cover`, ele vai crescer para ocupar todo o tamanho do `container`, isso já seria esperado... Eu troquei o cover por 100%, acho que o resultado ficou um pouco melhor, mas vc vai ter que ver qual melhor opção pra vc, e qual o melhor tamanho pra essa imagem...

**OBS:** 600px é um `@media` que é um valor que o Bootstrap não usa! Vc vai ter problemas de responsividade "quebrando" suas regras CSS pois esse *breacking point* não exite por default no grid do Bootstrap...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
    .navbar {
        padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
        background: url(https://www.placecage.com/400/100) no-repeat; 
        background-size: 100%;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .navbar .navbar-collapse{
            z-index: 999999999999999999999999999999;
            background-color: #343A40;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 20px;

            margin-left: -16px;
            margin-right: -16px;
            margin-bottom: -22px;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                      <!-- <img src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100" class="logo"> -->
                 </a>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPortfolio" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          Portfolio
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column Portfolio</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column Portfolio</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column Portfolio</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column Portfolio</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio Item</a>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          Blog
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          Other Pages
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="404.html">404</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show de bola Hugo. Mais uma vez, obrigado! Hoje devo tirar mais algumas dúvidas, pois tenho certas dificuldades com CSS rs rs rs.

Comment: @Fox.11 hahaha fique a vontade a meta é 200pt por dia  CSS é um assunto pouco compreendido. Mas vou te dar uma dica, pega uma semana, uma semaninha só, e faz um intensivão de CSS, refaz tutoriais, veja vídeos etc, 80% do CSS como um todo não se usa, já os outros 20% se usa 80% do tempo ;)

Comment: Perfeito Hugo. Obrigado pelas dicas. Vou fazer isso sim ;)

Answer (score 3):

Tente remover o padding do menu responsivo: conforme exemplo abaixo.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar .navbar-collapse{
        z-index: 999999999999999999999999999999;
        background-color: #343A40;
        /*padding: 10px;*/
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Renan. Seja bem-vindo! Infelizmente sua dica não funcionou, retirei o `padding: 10px`, mas o problema persiste.

Comment: Você tem um link para que possamos ver o projeto?

Comment: Ele está rodando localmente.